# Copy Editor badge "Go get it" link should point to Help and Improvement queue

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, help-improvement, activity-tab, badge-progress

Currently, the "*Go get it*" link for Copy Editor in the next badge widget is directing to [Low Quality Posts queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts).

[image: example of Go get it link]

I propose we point it to the [Help and Improvement queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper) instead. This queue is focused solely on editing while Low Quality Posts moderation options are less centered around editing.