# Copy Editor badge: Go Get It redirects to non-existing queue on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, profile-page, meta

In my [meta profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) the next non-tag badge proposed is [copy editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor). When I [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7A3n.gif) on it the popup offers me a link to [Go Get It](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts).

There is no review queue for Low Quality Posts on meta. So that link ends in a page not found. Not 100% sure how this can be fixed. One way would be to enable the Low Quality Posts queue, assuming we have that kind of posts on meta but maybe it is easier to link on meta to [Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

I did see this meta question [Copy Editor badge "Go get it" link should point to Help and Improvement queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292426/copy-editor-badge-go-get-it-link-should-point-to-help-and-improvement-queue) but that wouldn't solve this issue as H&I is also non-existent on Meta.

I do realize this probably is considered [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) as the markup is re-used from main and can't be easily altered.

Comment: On Meta, all posts are Low Quality, so it should just take you to the home page.

Comment: You could have some real fun and redirect it to their own answers page ;)

Comment: I'm known for my weird sense of humor @NathanOliver and by the looks of it you're infected ...

Comment: That means your pollen is spreading ...

Comment: Doesn't matter how easy it is to alter. Having a link that leads to a 404 in non-user-generated content is *always* a bug. Maybe it's a bug that has to sit open indefinitely because it can't be prioritized, but that isn't the same as being "by design" (aka, not a bug).

Comment: @adamlear So what was the fix?  Just get rid of the "go get it" part?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, less code and markup, less bugs, less UI design to break. A win-win situation ...

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, pretty much.

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks.  Just figured I would check since I saw it was gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential solution could be to just do away with the "Go get it!" button (or maybe even the "next badge" feature) on Meta. We'd generally much rather have users chasing down badges on the main site rather than on Meta, right?

Comment: *We'd generally much rather have users chasing down badges on the main site rather than on Meta, right?* Wait...what?...srsly? ... ;)

Comment: Do away was the solution implemented ... good call.